Install coq proof assistant from source - switch package not determined
On an M1 Mac under macOS Sonoma 14.5, I'm trying to install from source coq version 2023.11.0. At the step of "create opam switch", I get following error:
[CP.2023.11.0.patch_ocaml] Initialised
[CP.2023.11.0.patch_coq-released] Initialised
[CP.2023.11.0.patch_coq-dev] Initialised
[coq-released] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
[coq-core-dev] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/core-dev
[coq-extra-dev] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev

<><> Installing new switch packages <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
Switch invariant: ["ocaml-variants" {= "4.14.1+options"} "ocaml-option-flambda"]
[ERROR] Could not determine which packages to install for this switch:
  * Missing dependency:
    - ocaml-variants >= 4.14.1+options
    no matching version


Switch initialisation failed: clean up? ('n' will leave the switch partially installed) [y/n] y

That was on a second run of coq_platform_make.sh when the first run likewise stopped with the switch issue.
I'm using the prerequisite packages from MacPorts (not Homebrew!)
How fix and complete the installation?
Addendum 2024-07-14 Following the comments, I tried to install main from https://github.com/coq/platform.
Note (using MacPorts ocaml):
[~] ocaml --version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.14.1
And the README.md file for the version, (1), that I chose says that it uses OCaml 4.14.1.
However, that same README.md says "The OCaml version used is 4.14.1+options ocaml-option-flambda." No such option seems to be available with the MacPorts ocaml.
Here is the Terminal transcript, with the indicated failure, once again.
[~] % cd ~/Downloads/platform-main
[~/Downloads/platform-main] % ./coq_platform_make.sh
INFO: minimum MacOS version for the build has been set to 11.0
====================== JUST COQ OR COMPLETE PLATFORM ? =======================
This script installs the Coq Platform release 2024.01.0, that is:

- the Coq compiler and Coq's standard library (b)
- optionally CoqIDE, a GTK3 based graphical user interface (i)
- optionally various widely used Coq libraries and plugins (f)
- optionally an extended set of Coq libraries and plugins (x)

The script uses opam, the OCaml package manager, to do all the work.
In case opam is not yet installed, it will install opam.
A new opam switch will be created unless a Coq Platform switch already exists.

This script is tested on Windows 10, macOS and many Linux variants.

The script compiles everything from sources, which might takes less than one
hour on a fast machine with lot's of RAM, or up to 6 hours with little RAM.

Instead of installing the full or extended Coq Platform now, you can install
just Coq (+ CoqIDE) and install additional packages via opam later as needed.
You should install CoqIDE unless you know what VSCoq or Proof General is.
====================== JUST COQ OR COMPLETE PLATFORM ? =======================
Install full (f), extended (x), base (b) or IDE (i)? (f/x/b/i/c=cancel) f

========================= SELECT PACKAGE_PICK VERSION ==========================
The Coq Platform allows to install the latest release version of Coq, but also
older or development versions of Coq. Besides the Coq version, you can choose
a 'package pick', that is a selection of specific versions of Coq libraries,
plugins and tools. For some versions of Coq several package picks are available.
Package picks with the same release date for different Coq versions are made
as compatible as possible.
You can install several versions of Coq in parallel, which simplifies porting of
developments. You can use "opam switch" to switch between Coq versions.

The following Coq versions and package picks are available:
(1): Coq 8.18.0 (released Sep 2023) with the first package pick from Nov 2023
(2): Coq 8.18.0 (released Sep 2023) with a package pick based on mathcomp 2.1
(3): Coq 8.17.1 (released Jun 2023) with the first package pick from Aug 2023
(4): Coq 8.16.1 (released Nov 2022) with the first package pick from Sep 2022
(5): Coq 8.15.2 (released Jun 2022) with the first package pick from Apr 2022
(6): Coq 8.14.1 (released Nov 2021) with the first package pick from Jan 2022
(7): Coq 8.13.2 (released Apr 2021) with the first package pick from Feb 2021
(8): Coq 8.12.2 (released Dec 2020) with the first package pick from Dec 2020
(9): Coq 8.19.2 (released Jun 2024)
(10): Coq dev (latest master of all packages)
(11): Coq 8.16.1 (released Nov 2022) with an updated package pick from from Aug 2023
(12): Coq 8.15.2 (released Jun 2022) with an updated package pick from Sep 2022
(13): Coq 8.14.1 (released Nov 2021) with an updated package pick from Apr 2022
(14): Coq 8.13.2 (released Apr 2021) with an updated package pick from Jan 2022
(15): Coq 8.13.2 (released Apr 2021) with an extended package pick from Sep 2021

Please select a package pick by entering the number shown at the begin of a line.
========================= SELECT PACKAGE_PICK VERSION ==========================
Select package list (number in 1..15, c=cancel) 1

=============================== PARALLEL BUILD ===============================
The Coq Platform opam build has two levels of parallelism:

- parallel build of (independent) opam packages
- parallel build inside the make of each opam package

Since a single coqc call can take more than 1 GB of RAM and since the two
above kinds of parallelism multiply, the total amount of memory can be large.
But it is not as bad as one might expect: tests show that a full parallel
build takes less than 14GB of RAM with 15 parallel make jobs.

With 32 GB of RAM a parallel package build with 12 make jobs is recommended.
With 16 GB of RAM a parallel package build with 4 make jobs is recommended.
With 8 GB of RAM a sequential package build with 4 make jobs is recommended.
With 4 GB+1GB swap a sequential package build with 2 make jobs is recommended.
With less RAM, you might have to remove failing packages, e.g. VST.
In order to remove packages, just edit the file in the package_picks folder.

In case these recommendations don't work for you, please report an issue at:
https://github.com/coq/platform/issues
=============================== PARALLEL BUILD ===============================
Build opam packages parallel (p) or sequential (s)? (p/s/c=cancel) p

Number of parallel make jobs (number in 1..16, c=cancel) 4

================================== COMPCERT ==================================
The Coq Platform installs the formally verified C compiler CompCert.

CompCert is *not* free / open source software, but may be used for research and
evaluation purposes. Please clarify the license at:

https://github.com/AbsInt/CompCert/blob/master/LICENSE

In case you intend to use CompCert and your intended usage is in compliance
with the above license, please select "y" below, otherwise "n".

Please note that CompCert is required for the (open source) C verification
tool chain VST. If you don't install CompCert, you can't install VST.
If you want to use VST with the provided VST examples only, you require only
parts of CompCert, which are dual licensed and open source. In case you want
to verify your own C code with VST, you need non open source parts of
CompCert, notably the clightgen program. CompCert does not support
installing only its open source parts, since evaluation usage is explicitly
allowed in the license (see link above).
================================== COMPCERT ==================================
Install non open source SW CompCert (y) or (n)? (y/n/c=cancel) y

=============================== LARGE PACKAGES ===============================
The Coq Platform includes several packages which take a while to build.

The most time consuming packages are

  coq-vst:     a toolchain for verifying C code
  coq-unimath: a library for univalent mathematics
  coq-fiat-crypto, coq-bedrock2 and dependencies: (64 bit platforms only)
               Framework for correct by design code generation
               Cryptographic Primitive Code Generation by Fiat

Depending on your computer each of these packages takes between 10 minutes
and 2 hours to build. With just 4GB of RAM these packages might even fail
to build. In case you do not plan to use these packages, you can skip them
now. You can install them any time later with:

  opam install "package-name"
=============================== LARGE PACKAGES ===============================
Include (i) exclude (e) or select (s) large packages? (i/e/s/c=cancel) i

===== CHECKING VERSION OF INSTALLED OPAM =====
Found opam 2.2.0 - good!
/opt/local/bin/opam
===== opam already initialized =====
===== CREATE OPAM SWITCH =====
[CP.2024.01.0.patch_ocaml] Initialised
[CP.2024.01.0.patch_coq-released] Initialised
[CP.2024.01.0.patch_coq-dev] Initialised
[coq-released] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
[coq-core-dev] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/core-dev
[coq-extra-dev] no changes from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev

<><> Installing new switch packages <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
Switch invariant: ["ocaml-variants" {= "4.14.2+options"} "ocaml-option-flambda"]
[ERROR] Could not determine which packages to install for this switch:
  * Missing dependency:
    - ocaml-variants >= 4.14.2+options
    no matching version


Switch initialisation failed: clean up? ('n' will leave the switch partially
installed) [y/n] y

** Addendum #2**
Following a comment, I renamed ~/.opam and tried again. New issue:
<><> conf-gtk3.18 troubleshooting <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
=> This package requires gtk+ 3.0 development packages installed on your system
=> To solve pkg-config issues, you may need to do
   'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig' and retry

<><> cairo2.0.6.4 troubleshooting <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
=> Try to re-run the install command with PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing a pkg-config
   path including libffi, e.g. if you use homebrew you can try
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig

The former state can be restored with:
    /opt/local/bin/opam switch import
"/Users/murray/.opam/CP.2024.01.0~8.18~2023.11/.opam-switch/backup/state-20240718000214.export"


You seem to have chosen the "dev" package pick - this is not well maintained because it breaks frequently and is low prio. Please use one of the release versions.
If you absolutely need dev, you can try to change this line:
https://github.com/coq/platform/blob/0f6181d8134d0c05aad61673878bea3da25aded6/package_picks/package-pick-dev.sh#L34
to OCaml 4.14.2. Most packages should build then.
Help with maintaining the dev pick would be very welcome!

I don't understand that. In any case, I just installed from the MacOS (arm) installer for 8.18.0 at https://github.com/coq/platform/releases/tag/2023.11.0. that worked -- except for annoying "file is damaged and cannot be opened" issue, remedied by the usual  xattr -d com.apple.quarantine business.

At the second step of the installation, the script asked you which version of coq you want to install and as far as I can tell you selected there the option:
(10): Coq dev (latest master of all packages)

This option is not well maintained because it is hard to maintain a moving target. All other options should work.
I believe you picked this option, because the dev opam repos are included according to the logs you posted, which is otherwise not the case.

And yes, INRIA is working on the MacOS signing process (since a while).

@M Soegtrop: Actually, I think I selected (1).

I see. Did you get a recent version from main or a tag? OCaml 4.14.1 which was current when the latest tag was made does not work on Sonoma. This is fixed in main, but there is no tag yet.

@M Soegstrup : following recommendation at platform/doc/README_macOS.md, i downloaded github.com/coq/platform/archive/refs/tags/2023.11.0.zip and ran the indicated script. At some point during the build I was asked to choose a number from a list of numbers and, having no idea what the numbers meant, just chose “1”. I know no more about what was going on than that,

I'm using MacPorts, and latest OCaml there is 4.14.1.

@murray - yes we are working on a release more or less since Christmas. So the documentation is a bit stale. Please use main on MacOS. The scripts install their own OCaml with Opam and there 4.14.2 does work. 4.14.1 does not work with XCode 15.X - some change in linking logic. Since MacPorts does not work with XCode 14.X on Sonoma, you are bound to XCode 15.X and with that to OCaml 4.14.2.

@M Soegtrop: where is that "main"? And is it really necessary to install from sources on an Apple silicon (M1) machine, given that there is available a .dmg installer for that?

@murray: Coq Platform main is simply here:
https://github.com/coq/platform
(The main branch is called main and not master). If you are happy with what the DMG provides, this is perfectly fine and the preferred solution. The compile from sources method is intended for advanced users who need opam to install additional packages.

But I am interested to understand what is going wrong for you.

@M Soegstrop: Please see Addendum to my original post.showing lastest, failed, attempt, now using main.

@murray: I would say something is broken with your opam setup. Can you please try to rename the ~/.opam folder to ~/.opam_bak and try again? This will create a fresh opam folder. You can easily undo this be renaming it back.

I also need to check opam 2.2 - I am still on 2.1.6. One cannot exclude that something broke with opam 2.2.

After renaming ~/.opam the reinstall failed, at a new point. Please sed Addendu #2 at the end of my original post.

Thanks for your test efforts. This looks like a broken homebrew.
Can it be that you imported user data from an Intel Mac to an Apple silicon Mac by some sort of automated migration? This also imports a lot of intel libraries in homebrew and opam and generally leaves your system in an unusable state. If you did this, you need to completely erase and reinstall first homebrew and then opam. Otherwise you end up with a mix of intel stuff running via Rosetta and ARM stuff and this will fail at some point.

As I said before, I’m using MacPorts and not Homebrew

Well then it looks like a broken MacPorts. Again the question: did you do a user data migration from an Intel to an Apple silicon Mac?

Data migration of what? MacPorts was freshly installed on my current M1 Mac, and all the relevant ports were installed afresh on this machine.

There have been reports that the general process of migrating user data from an Intel Mac to an ARM Mac frequently results in a setup which has some mixture of intel and ARM libraries in whatever package managers one uses (MacPorts, homebrew, opam, conda, software like OCaml or opam installed with scripts, you name it). For this reason I asked if you ever did such a user account migration. And please take my apologises if I ask the same question twice - Coq Platform has quite a few users and I support many of them in parallel and can't remember all details in parallel.

When I migrated from an Intel to an ARM Mac, I completely re-installed MacPorts itself and all the ports I use.

What is happening is this: opam runs:
sudo port install gtk3 +quartz
and then
pkg-config --short-errors --print-errors --atleast-version 3.18 gtk+-3.0
to check if GTK3 is indeed installed
The first appears to pass on your system (hard to tell from the log fragment), the second fails. If this is so, your MacPorts installation is broken for a reason I cannot tell. There is also the possibility that opam has a bug - you can check this by running the above command manually. Note that pkg-config fails silently - you need to run echo $? afterwards to get the status.
